# What function should I use to return a vector of characters?

Tags: r, function, if-statement, vector

So I have a data set that looks like this:

```
  state.x77[1,]
```

Population     Income Illiteracy   Life Exp     Murder    HS Grad      Frost 
   3615.00    3624.00       2.10      69.05      15.10      41.30      20.00 
      Area 
  50708.00

> as.numeric(state.x77[1,])
>   [1]  3615.00  3624.00     2.10    69.05    15.10    41.30    20.00 50708.00

I want something that looks like this:
`[1] "Arizona" "Washington"

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could first select the columns for which you want to apply `mean` and `sd`. Assuming you want columns that end with `"P"`. Then calculate row-wise `sd` and row-wise `mean` and compare the values and return the corresponding `gene_symbol`.

```
cols <- grep("P$", names(df))
df$gene_symbol[apply(df[cols],1,sd, na.rm = TRUE) > rowMeans(df[cols],na.rm = TRUE)]
```

To calculate `sd` we can also use `rowSds` function from `matrixStats` package

```
library(matrixStats)
df$gene_symbol[rowSds(as.matrix(df[cols]), na.rm = TRUE) > 
               rowMeans(df[cols], na.rm = TRUE)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `purrr` solution:

```
df[pmap_lgl(df %>% select(starts_with("L0")), ~sd(c(...))>mean(c(...))), "gene_symbol"]
```

This passes all columns beginning with `L0` to a function that compares the `sd` and `mean` then returns a logical vector which selects the relevant rows from the data frame. (This assumes your data frame is called `df`.) `dplyr` is required for the pipe operator and `select` function.